# What effect would result from always keeping Page time >> Age of universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, hawking-radiation, unitarity

A thought experiment:  I imagine, similar to early theories (eg: Hoyle),
that the universe’s mass is not constant, but increases over cosmic
time, in such a way that even the thinnest vacuum will contain enough
mass to always increase the mass of all black holes by simple accretion.
Thus no BH will ever reach its Page time (where it has Hawking-radiated-
away half its total mass).  Would this nullify the information loss paradox
and save unitarity?